# Truffle: Migrate to ropsten, unknown network "true" error

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, dapps, ropsten, truffle-migration

I am trying to deploy a work in progress dapp to the ropsten network using:

`truffle migrate --network ropsten`

I have a geth instance running in terminal and I receive the following error:

`Unknown network "true". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks.`

This is my truffle.js file:

```
    module.exports = {
      networks: {
        development: {
          host: "localhost",
          port: 8545,
          network_id: "*" // Match any network id
        },
        ropsten: {
          network_id: 3,
          host: "localhost",
          from: "<<Address is usually here>>",
          port: 8545,
          gas: 2900000
        }
      }
    };
```

EDIT: I am using ubuntu for development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed after a fresh install of truffle

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, make sure you're using `truffle-config.js` otherwise use `truffle.js` for configuration. I usually keep both files in sync to avoid confusion.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu for development so I don't think I have truffle-config.js, only truffle.js. I will edit the post.

Comment: Somehow your network is being evaluated as 'true' instead of 'ropsten'. Configuration file looks fine but re-check for any typos in your file in case it's not exactly as pasted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how beneficial now, but for future reference: I've moved on from truffles configs as I've had some problems on the mainnet. I've been deploying for some time using plain old node.js scripts and I've even written a small library to help me out. Here is a snippet:

```
const etherlime = require('etherlime');

const ICOTokenContract = require('./build/contracts/ICOToken.json');

const randomAddress = '0xda8a06f1c910cab18ad187be1faa2b8606c2ec86';

const defaultConfigs = {
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 4700000
}

const deployer = new etherlime.InfuraPrivateKeyDeployer('Your Privste KEY', 'ropsten', 'Your infura API key', defaultConfigs);

const runICODeployment = async () => {
    const contractWrapper = await deployer.deploy(ICOTokenContract);
    const transferTransaction = await contractWrapper.contract.transferOwnership(randomAddress);
    const result = await contractWrapper.verboseWaitForTransaction(transferTransaction.hash, 'Transfer Ownership');
}
runICODeployment()
```

Paste this in a file, change your contracts